# how to restrict the number of availability domains in OCI odo_deployment

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a region that has three Availability domains. I need to deploy my odo application in only 2 ads skipping the 3rd ad.

I could that in Infrastructure deployment module under odo_applicaiton since it allows count variable in it.

```
resource "odo_application" "myapp_reg_api" {
  count                     = local.regionname == "xyz" ? 2 : 1
  ad                        = var.availability_domains[count.index].name
```

How can i achieve the same in odo_deployment in application deployment.

```
resource "odo_deployment" "myapp_reg_api_deployment" {
  for_each = var.ad_map
  //ad       = each.key
  //ad       = var.availability_domains[count.index].name. <<-- count is not a field in odo_deployment

I want to say something like if my region is "xyz" then only deploy in ad-1 and ad-2. For other regions it can be in all ads.
```